# Kinetic Energy based superpowers?

Tags: aliens, super-powers

I'm designing a species with a rather large amount of superpowers, and I'm making the basis being able to control or manipulate Kinetic energy (the type of energy that moves molecules to cause heat, and causes objects to move) with their minds. Some powers that I have figured such a species would have would be telekinesis, the ability to heat or cool things at will, and fly. What other powers would someone like this have?

Comment: This is the third extremely broad very opinion based question you have asked on this site. Please take the [tour] and read the [faq] in the [help] center so you can better understand what is necessairy to ask a good question on this site. If you are unsure if a question is a good fit for this site or not I'd suggest using the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to get feedback on a question before asking it on the main site.

Comment: @sphennings i have read through both the tour and help center, and have found nothing saying not to ask opinionated or broad questions. I am not sure in what way this question is broad, and as for opinion based, most of the questions on this site are based on what the answerer believes is the right or wrong answer. There is no real way to have a fact-based answer in such a quesion involving world building or superpowers.

Comment: To quote from the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question." It looks like you are wanting to do a brainstorming session which isn't the purpose of this site.

Comment: @sphennings my question is very much indeed answerable (albeit not by me). Furthermore my question is, in my opinion rather specific, giving a basis for such abilities to be given, and not simply asking for any powers in general.

Comment: "The movement of molecules" is more commonly called heat. As for controlling "the movement of an object" the vast majority of people can do it.

Comment: @AlexP ahh, fair point. I shall edit that question momentarily!

Comment: Like you said, the two most obvious powers the species would have is to heat/cool things with their mind (which I'd call thermokinesis) and telekinesis. Thermokinesis could be developed into your standard pyrokinesis. One thing to think about is how 'hard' do you want the physics to be in your world. Is there conservation of energy?

Comment: @Eriek Yes, his body is using up large amount of Chemical energy stored in his body.

Comment: This question violates our "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" limitations on questions.  It's a "fishing for ideas" question.  Stack Exchange's focus is Q&A, not forum discussion.  (If you didn't find these issues reading the FAQ and Meta, you weren't looking very hard.)  The reason is that a proper quesiton can and will result in one best answer.  This question cannot.